# save user id as login data permanently for iOS app with swift

Tags: ios, rest, swift, user-registration, userid

I've implemented a REST API Webservice and my iOS app creates requests to this webservice like a registration of an user. The REST webservice responses the user id if successful. A typical login is not a part of a REST webservice. Now I want to save this user id on the iPhone for this app, so I don't have to login everytime on starting the app. But how is it possible. How should I do this with swift? And what is the typical way to do this in an iPhone app?

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to check the [documentation for NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the "user id" you want to save need to be secret? If not that actually might be a good candidate for NSUserDefaults. If is needs to be secret use the Keychain.

For an example of using the Keychain from Swift see this: [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25513335/451475)

Comment: Yes the user id should be secret because of privacy. I use also https for all communications and maybe later TLS.

Comment: Added Keychain example link.